# Bulk trigger in salesforce in order

Tags: trigger

How to write bulk trigger for this code:

```
trigger deleiverydateclaculation on Order (before insert) 
{
    for(order ce:trigger.new)
    {
        if(ce.Number_of_Deleiveries__c==2)
        {
            ce.Deleivery_Date1__c = system.today();
            ce.Deleivery_Date_2__c = ce.Deleivery_Date1__c.addmonths(6);
        }
        else if(ce.Number_of_Deleiveries__c==3)
        {
            ce.Deleivery_Date1__c = system.today();
            ce.Deleivery_Date_2__c = ce.Deleivery_Date1__c.addmonths(4);
            ce.Deleivery_Date_3__c = ce.Deleivery_Date_2__c.addmonths(4);
        }
    }
}
```

please anyone guide me write the bulk trigger code

Comment: What part of this code isn't bulk?

Comment: trigger.new is for single record only @nicecook

Comment: As you don't have any DMl, SOQL inside the trigger so this trigger is already bulkified. Although you can use trigger handler class to write your logic. Trigger.new will give you list so its bulkified.

Comment: @user36188 No, trigger.new contains a list of new records. Why would you use a 'for' loop for a single record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good for the bulk case already.

As Tushar mentions, it is usually database operations subject to governor limits that prompt "bulkification": as a trigger can get called with 200 records, doing a query inside the record loop when only 100 queries are allowed per transaction is something to be avoided.

On the subject of why loop over the records, a trigger, like any piece of code, should respect any documented contract and the [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) documentation and other documentation makes it clear that multiple records can be involved. So while a trigger might most of the time only be invoked for one record (e.g. as a result of a user's action though the UI on one record) code that you don't know about today or admin work in the future may well cause the trigger to run for many records.

(Any time I have written code including outside of triggers that does not handle the bulk case well I've generally regretted it down the line when some new requirement has meant that many records have to be handled at once. The more convoluted logic required for the bulk case is a penalty we have to pay on the platform.)